# MySQL Workbench - I want to loop through 100 columns which are named `1`-`100`

Tags: mysql, loops, variables, insert

I am using MySQL Workbench.  I am trying to build a table with random dummy data that I am generating using a loop.  I want to loop through 100 columns which are named 1-100.  How can this be accomplished?

Here is what I have so far. I get Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertUsingLoop3$$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertUsingLoop3()
BEGIN
   DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE randValue INT DEFAULT 33;
   
   WHILE count < 101 DO
        SET randValue = FLOOR( RAND() * (127-33) + 33);
        INSERT INTO test1(count)
            VALUES(CHAR(randValue));
      SET count = count + 1;
   END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I was hoping to use the variable - 'count' as the column name since I named 100 columns using the numbers 1 - 100.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this approach , you can only insert to an existing table - you haven't created test in the sp or told use you created it outwith the sp,, an insert inserts to a row so if your code was worked you would end up with 100 rows each with 1 column populated, You cannot dynamically allocate the column to be populated without using prepared statments, 'Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.' -

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html#:~:text=Certain%20objects%20within%20MySQL%2C%20including,names%20are%20known%20as%20identifiers.

Comment: Is it your intention to end up with a table consisting of 1 row with 100 columns??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query as a string and then execute it.
In your case, the query may be as follows:

```
WHILE count < 101 DO
   SET randValue = FLOOR( RAND() * (127-33) + 33);
   SET @q = CONCAT('INSERT INTO test1(c', count,') VALUES(CHAR(',randValue, '))');
   PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   SET count = count + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I got the following error.  14:13:13 call insertUsingLoop3() Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '33) VALUES(CHAR( 88))' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: @DerekOlson, I think the problem is in your column names. I edited the answer and assumed that the column names start with a letter 'c'. for example `c1`, `c2` ... instead of `1` , `2` ,...   
try this and let me know if you had any problems.

Comment: @P.Salmnon No, I didn't mean to have a single column, rather, 100 columns. I'll try to alter the table, pre-pending a "c" for the names and try again. I'm trying different things. Using php to do the loop also. It seems easier to me since I'm more familiar with it than sql.

Comment: @DerekOlson, you need to put that in a procedure and the call it.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP with WAMP I was able to figure out a solution to what I was trying to do. Here is what I came up with.

```
    function insColmns() {
  // loop through columns named '1', '2', ... '98', '99', '100'
  $counter1 = 1;
  $colmns = '';

  while($counter1 <= 100) {
      $strCounter1 = (string) $counter1;
      if($counter1 < 100) {
        $colmns .= 'c' . $strCounter1 . ', ';
      } else {
        $colmns .= 'c' . $strCounter1;
      }
      
      $counter1++;
  }

  return $colmns;
}

function insData() {
  // loop to insert random character into each of the columns
  $counter2 = 1;
  $data = '';

  while($counter2 <= 100) {
    $randValue = rand(384,591);
    $unicodeChar1 = (string) mb_chr($randValue);

    if($counter2 < 100) {
      $data .= '"' . $unicodeChar1 . '", '; 
    } else {
      $data .= '"' . $unicodeChar1 . '"';
    }

    $counter2++;
  }

  return $data;
}


$sql = 'INSERT INTO testing.sample2 (' . insColmns() .
')
VALUES (' . insData() . ')';
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped me figure this out!  I learned a lot!